# Could not find 'librealm-jni.so'. Looked for: [x86], but only found: []

Tags: android, android-ndk, realm

My app has been working smoothly for the last few months. But since last week I have been getting the following error a lot,

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.foo.bar.MyApplication: com.getkeepsafe.relinker.MissingLibraryException: Could not find 'librealm-jni.so'. Looked for: [x86], but only found: [].
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5743)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

This issue has 40 crash events affecting 7 users (My app only has less than 3000 installs).

These are the affected devices,

```
Nexus 5X
HUAWEI WDGF4587
QEMU Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009) <= Someone experimenting with my apk?
Motorola One Vision (rooted)
```

for a [similar issue,](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-android/issues/576#issuecomment-494148605)
someone suggested to use `android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false`

[This blog post](https://corbt.com/posts/2015/09/18/mixing-32-and-64bit-dependencies-in-android.html) says that Android won't be able to load 32- and 64-bit native libraries concurrently. In my app, I'm also using other libraries such as `uCrop` and my own native codes. The solution he suggested is to simply exclude all 64-bit binaries from your APK.

Does anyone know the implications of the above-mentioned fixes?

Comment: Neither the Nexus 5X nor the Motorola One Vision are x86 devices. Maybe these are all emulators with spoofed device names? In any case, there have been no new x86-based Android devices made in several years AFAIK. There might be some x86_64 ones (Chromebooks?).

Comment: _"The solution he suggested is to simply exclude all 64-bit binaries from your APK"_ That would probably be a bad idea, since you wouldn't be allowed to publish your app on Google Play if it contains 32-bit native libraries but no 64-bit counterparts.

Comment: So, I can safely ignore this error?

Comment: Safely ignore? Probably not, it's crashing for users. I still don't have a solution for this, though. Anyone?

Answer (score -1):

You specified the cpu architecture of the response in your project. I think it's a cpu architecture configuration issue.

Comment: I didn't specify the CPU architecture. By default ```cmake``` will build libs for all available architectures. I have unpacked the release ```.aab``` file and I can see ```.so``` files for all platforms. (BTW this should be a comment :-))